# How things are like? vs What things are like

Tags: grammar

I wrote, "I don't know how things are like nowadays." And my friend responded

> One cannot say "how things are like", it is grammatically incorrect.
>
> You can say "what things are like" because the "what" refers to a
> noun, or you can say "how things are" (without "like") because the
> "how" refers to a manner.

Is he correct?

Comment: Well you *can* say it, and you will be understood, but he is correct that it is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: @nnnnnn you are just being prescriptive instead of descriptive

Comment: You could also say "how things are" instead of "how things are like". But definitely changing the "how" to a "what" there sounds a lot more natural to a native speaker.

Comment: It's *not* actually ungrammatical. It's simply very unusual, and would normally be taken as the wrong word. In the sense that it's almost certainly being expressed, it's incorrect for that context.

Comment: However, an answer to the implicit question *as literally written* (and grammatical) could be the following: **The world is behaving *like* a sick person at present.**

Comment: I don't think I'm being prescriptive, I'm indicating that most people will find that usage odd at best, which is a descriptive view not a prescriptive one. Though apparently (as per Jason's comment) it's not actually incorrect.

Comment: @JasonBassford I would accept your answer if you put in a proper answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of *how things are like* is highly unusual, although not actually ungrammatical.

---

I find it doubtful that anybody would actually mean to use *how* in that sentence. Most likely, what they actually mean should be expressed with *what* instead:

> "I don't know **what** things are like nowadays."
> "Why, they're crazy."

If this is what's meant, then using *how* instead of *what* is a mistake.

---

However, if the use of *how* is deliberate, then it's both grammatical *and* actually sensible:

> "I don't know **how** things are like nowadays."
> "Why, the whole world's behaving like a sick person."

In other words, both *how* and *like* are used in their normal sense, allowing the original sentence to be rephrased as follows:

> "I can't think of an analogy for the manner in which things are functioning these days."

---

So, you *can* say the sentence in the question, using *how* rather than *what*, and have it make sense. However, it's unlikely for the person saying it to actually mean it in the sense that allows *how* to be a reasonable word choice.

If somebody actually *does* want to express the *how* meaning, it would be better for them to rephrase the sentence so there is no confusion on the part of anybody hearing it.